# Need RegEx Pattern To Match '--'

Tags: c#, regex

Here's some input

```
 36    1   36   0ef6c0   id     N8   Online      FC  F-Port  50:05:07:68:01:80:fc:ae 
 37    1   37   0ef680   id     N8   Online      FC  F-Port  50:05:07:68:01:80:fa:1b 
 38    1   38   0ef640   id     N8   Online      FC  F-Port  50:05:07:68:01:80:fa:2e 
  39    1   39   0ef600   id     N8   Online      FC  F-Port  50:05:07:68:01:80:f9:ca 
86    2   22   0eea40   --    --   Online      VE  VE-Port  10:00:00:05:33:ea:da:4d "replsa2v" (downstream)
87    2   23   0eea00   --    --   Offline     VE  Disabled (Persistent) 
88    2   24   0ee9c0   --    --   Offline     VE  Disabled (Persistent)
```

This regular expression matches the first 4 lines.

```
(?<index>\d+)\s+(?<slot>\d+)\s+(?<port>\d+)\s+(?<address>\w{6,})\s+\b(id|cu)\b\s+(?<speed>\w\d+)\s+\b(?<state>\w+)\s+(?<protocol>\S+)\s+(?<type>\S+)\s(?<extra>.*)
```

This one matches the last 3

```
(?<index>\d+)\s+(?<slot>\d+)\s+(?<port>\d+)\s+(?<address>\w{6,})\s+[-]{2}\s+[-]{2}\s+\b(?<state>\w+)\s+(?<protocol>\S+)\s+(?<type>\S+)\s(?<extra>.*)
```

I'd like one pattern that matches all.  The code works but it would be cleaner and slightly faster if I was doing a single match.  The best I can do with a single pattern is to match the first half of the first 4 lines of input  and the last half of the last 3 - basically everything before the first '--' and after the last one.

Comment: I didn't know there were filters against the word 'Help'.  Helop was a typo and not intentional.

Comment: The edited title is much better, although it doesn't really explain what you're asking yet. Matching *--* is quite easy. You're looking to do more than that, aren't you? (Misspelling to get past filters happens often here.) I'll delete the comment, as it's no longer needed anyway. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this work for me:

```
(?<index>\d+)\s+
(?<slot>\d+)\s+
(?<port>\d+)\s+
(?<address>\w{6,})\s+
(id|cu|-{2})\s+
(?<speed>\w\d+|-{2})\s+
\b(?<state>\w+)\s+
(?<protocol>\S+)\s+
(?<type>\S+)\s
(?<extra>.*)
```

Comment: thanks.  Looking at yours I see my mistake was leaving the \b\b tags in the pattern.